# PyMongo aggregation function

Tags: mongodb

Need solution of code which is aimed at finding out the total number of movies by genre. The code I am using is:

```
agg_result = movies_collection.aggregate(
[{"$match": {}},{"$group":
       {"_id":"$genres", 
        "Total movie count":{"$sum":1}
       }}
])
for i in agg_result:
    print(i)
```

I need movies by each genre but since uploaded csv file has multiple entries in genre field the sample output is coming wrong.

Sample output coming as:
{'_id': 'Animation|Children|Comedy|Fantasy', 'Total movie count': 6}
{'_id': 'Action|Drama|Horror|IMAX', 'Total movie count': 1}

Answer (score 0):

Query

- split the genre string on "|"
- unwind so each document 1 genre
- group and count the genres

*i think you should also update the collection and make the genre a normal array, having strings with "|" doesn't seem good schema.

[Playmongo](https://cmql.org/playmongo/?q=62806134853f039c69b0f8da)

```js
aggregate(
[{"$set": {"genres": {"$split": ["$genres", "|"]}}},
 {"$unwind": "$genres"},
 {"$group": {"_id": "$genres", "count": {"$sum": 1}}}])
```

Comment: i was thinking the same (splitting the collection substring into individual strings) but can they be put into the same field (ex: genre will have individual strings in it?

Also, is the example code correct to sort substring?

txt = "Grumpier Old Men (1995)"

x = txt.split('(')
m = x[1]
y = m[0:len(m)-1]

print(y)